# Maya python check if mesh has animation

Tags: python, maya

I'm looping through the selected objects in maya and trying to check if they have either Transform or Deforming animation. Is there a way to check for this? I found out how to check for the Transform animation, but not sure how to check deformation animation, which would be vertex based animations or bone driven animations.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


def hasTransformAnimation(transform):
    if cmds.objExists(transform):
        animAttributes = cmds.listAnimatable(transform)
        for attribute in animAttributes:
            numKeyframes = cmds.keyframe(attribute, query=True, keyframeCount=True)
            if numKeyframes > 0:
                return True
    return False


def hasDeformationAnimation(transform):
    return False



sel = cmds.ls(sl=True, l=True, type=('transform'))
for o in sel:
    print('Transform', o, hasTransformAnimation(o))
    print('Deformation', o, hasDeformationAnimation(o))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by simply checking if either the transform node has incomming connections to the transformation attributes or if the mesh shape has in incoming connection connected to the `inMesh` attribute. The only drawback of this method is that you cannot see if the geometry is really animated or if it is static.